# Why is NSolve returning an empty list?

Tags: equation-solving

When I evaluate the code shown below, I'm obtaining `{ }` and I don't know why. Can anyone can help me, please.

```
datos = 
  {vmax1 -> 1, s0 -> 200, vmax2 -> 2.1, k1 -> 0.15, k2 -> 0.01, k3 -> 0.03, 
   k4 -> 0.2, k5 -> 0.001, k6 -> 2, k7 -> 1.3, k8 -> 2.2, k9 -> 0.5, k10 -> 2.2, 
   vmax3 -> 3.2, vmax4 -> 5, P -> 300};

v1 := ((vmax1/(1 + s2/k1)) s0)/(s0 + k2);
v1 /. datos
v2 := (vmax2 s1)/(s1 + k3 (1 + s2/k4));
v2 /. datos
v3 := (vmax3 (s2 - s3/k5))/(s2 + k6 (1 + s3/k7));
v3 /. datos
v4 := ((vmax4/(1 + s1/k8)) s3)/(s3 + (k9/(1 + s1/k10)))
v4 /. datos
sol = NSolve[{v1 == v2 == v3 == v4} /. datos, {s1, s2, s3}, Reals]
```

Comment: `sol = NSolve[{v1 == v2, v2 == v3, v3 == v4} /. datos, {s1, s2, s3}, 
  Reals]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
datos = {vmax1 -> 1, s0 -> 200, vmax2 -> 2.1, k1 -> 0.15, k2 -> 0.01, 
    k3 -> 0.03, k4 -> 0.2, k5 -> 0.001, k6 -> 2, k7 -> 1.3, k8 -> 2.2, 
    k9 -> 0.5, k10 -> 2.2, vmax3 -> 3.2, vmax4 -> 5, P -> 300} // Rationalize;

v1 = ((vmax1/(1 + s2/k1)) s0)/(s0 + k2);
v2 = (vmax2 s1)/(s1 + k3 (1 + s2/k4));
v3 = (vmax3 (s2 - s3/k5))/(s2 + k6 (1 + s3/k7));
v4 = ((vmax4/(1 + s1/k8)) s3)/(s3 + (k9/(1 + s1/k10)));

sol = NSolve[v1 == v2 == v3 == v4 /. datos, {s1, s2, s3}]

(* {{s1 -> 825.08, s2 -> -0.0785734, s3 -> -0.00133813}, {s1 -> 0.0103752, 
  s2 -> -3.92151, s3 -> -0.00394546}, {s1 -> 0.011045, s2 -> 3.84842, 
  s3 -> 0.00377979}, {s1 -> -0.00752558, s2 -> -0.1499, s3 -> -0.503403}} *)
```

Verifying

```
v1 == v2 == v3 == v4 /. datos /. sol

(* {False, False, False, False} *)
```

There is a loss of precision issue. Use arbitrary precision rather than machine precision.

```
sol2 = NSolve[v1 == v2 == v3 == v4 /. datos, {s1, s2, s3}, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 16]

(* {{s1 -> 825.080413737832, s2 -> -0.0785734230854370, 
  s3 -> -0.001338130811488813}, {s1 -> 0.01037522791875470, 
  s2 -> -3.92150598736372, 
  s3 -> -0.00394546209520146}, {s1 -> 0.01104502536865346, 
  s2 -> 3.84842147258573, 
  s3 -> 0.00377979348539405}, {s1 -> -0.00752558327175948, 
  s2 -> -0.1498998162290211, s3 -> -0.503403179507142}} *)
```

Verifying

```
v1 == v2 == v3 == v4 /. datos /. sol2

(* {True, True, True, True} *)
```

Comment: Thank you, i appreciate your time and your answer!